# How To Have One Input Be Reused And Add To A List In Python 3.x.x

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that will add numerical inputs into an array and then find the sum of. I would prefer typing every number individually and then looping back to the input and adding it all to a list when the user is finished, but it seems like typing out 3, 3, 3, 3 would be easier. I also want a custom amount of numbers on the list ex. 32, 3, 5. And then the next time maybe 52, 3, 3, 22. How would I add this function?

I have tried using define functions to loop back to the start and also loops. I have tried to put 1, 1, 1 into the input. I have also tried changing it to a string.

```
numberarrayinput = 0
while not numberarrayinput == -100:
     numberarrayinput = int(input("Enter In Your Numbers One By One. Type -100 If You Are Done.\n"))
numberlist = []
numberlist = [numberarrayinput]
print(numberlist)
arraytotal = sum(numberlist)
```

I expected the output of 3,3,3,3 to return and print 23 at the end, but, I get an invalid literal error for int(). I do not know how to create a new list value so if I input just 5 it will return 5.

Comment: You got an "*invalid literal*" because you entered a non number (e.g. a letter). To handle that use a *try* / *except* or better: `numberarrayinput.isdigit()` (`numberarrayinput = input(...`). Appending the number in the list should also happen inside the loop.

Comment: Why are you using `not ... == ...` instead of `... != ...`?

Comment: Your code seems to (be trying to) accept input of one number per line. Do you want to input comma-separated numbers instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numberarrayinput = 0
numberlist = []
while not numberarrayinput == -100:
    numberlist.append(numberarrayinput)
    numberarrayinput = int(input("Enter In Your Numbers One By One. Type -100 If You Are Done.\n"))
print(numberlist)
arraytotal = sum(numberlist)
print(arraytotal)
```

Is this what you're looking for?
The problem is you weren't appending new values to your array. only the last number you entered, which in your case is always -100;